# How do I access an objects key in bracket notation?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I can't seem to figure out how to access the spearguns object using bracket notation.  I'm trying to access the "heft" key.  The console log say's "undefined".  Any help would be great, thanks.

```
var rockSpearguns = {
  Sharpshooter: {barbs: 2, weight: 10, heft: "overhand"},
  Pokepistol: {barbs: 4, weight: 8, heft: "shoulder"},
  Javelinjet: {barbs: 4, weight: 12, heft: "waist"},
  Firefork: {barbs: 6, weight: 8, heft: "overhand"},
  "The Impaler": {barbs: 1, weight: 30, heft: "chest"}
};

function listGuns(guns) {
  for (var speargun in guns) {
    // modify the log message here
    console.log("Behold! " + speargun + ", with " + this["heft"] + " heft!");
  }
}

listGuns(rockSpearguns);
```

Comment: notation is ok, but `this` is not what you think it is

Comment: you need more read about [this keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: Thanks guys, you're right.  "this" wasn't what I thought it was.  I instead used:


console.log("Behold! " + speargun + ", with " + guns[speargun]["heft"] + " heft!");

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I ended up using:

```
function listGuns(guns) {
  for (var speargun in guns) {
    // modify the log message here

    console.log("Behold! " + speargun + ", with " + guns[speargun]["heft"] + " heft!");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a reference to the gun from the property name like this:

```
var rockSpearguns = {
                Sharpshooter: {barbs: 2, weight: 10, heft: "overhand"},
                Pokepistol: {barbs: 4, weight: 8, heft: "shoulder"},
                Javelinjet: {barbs: 4, weight: 12, heft: "waist"},
                Firefork: {barbs: 6, weight: 8, heft: "overhand"},
                "The Impaler": {barbs: 1, weight: 30, heft: "chest"}
};

function listGuns(guns) {
    for (var speargun in guns) {
        // modify the log message here
        var gun = guns[speargun];
        console.log("Behold! " + speargun + ", with " + gun["heft"] + " heft!");
    }
}
```